# Click Button that fills an textArea & submits it

Tags: javascript, github, textarea

I'm working with github issue i want to create a button that will fill the comment textarea and submit.

So far so good, i need to bind the function in a button,

at the moment i managed to fill the textarea but couldn't submit the comment 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXhtj.png)

```
  clickToRespond=()=>{
    document.getElementById('new_comment_field').value='This is a test'
    document.getElementsByClassName('bg-gray-light ml-1').click()
  }
```

Solution : `document.getElementsByClassName('bg-gray-light ml-1')[0].childNodes[1].click()`

Comment: Can you please explain with example of what you want ? I didn't quite get it

Comment: @mrid, I created a button on github, when you open an issue and you click on the button, it will fill the textarea of the comment and submit it, at the moment i only managed to fill the textarea but couldn't find a way to submit it cause the node of the Element is Changing as soon as i submit a new comment

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list of DOM nodes. So you want to do this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('bg-gray-light ml-1')[0].click()
```

Comment: as soon as it's become submited it change node value, is there a way to find out how to handle this ,